# How to create the Database in Postgreql with ISO 8859-1 Character set?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to create the database named "MUSIC" in PostgreSQL with ISO 8859-1 Character Set. I am getting the below error:

```
testdb=# CREATE DATABASE MUSIC WITH ENCODING 'ISO 8859-1';

ERROR:  encoding "LATIN1" does not match locale "English_India.1252"
DETAIL: The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding "WIN1252".
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want a single-byte encoding, use `WIN1252`. It is a strict superset of ISO 8859-1 and is available on Windows (in the typical Microsoft style of [embrace, extend and extinguish](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish)).

But there is no good reason to use an encoding other than `UTF8`, and that is what I recommend you to use.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding "WIN1252", example:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE database_name WITH TABLESPACE tablespace_name TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = database_user ENCODING 'WIN1252' LC_CTYPE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252' LC_COLLATE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252';
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=#
postgres=# \l
```

List of databases

```
     Name      |     Owner     | Encoding |        Collate         | Ctype |  Access privileges
 database_name | database_user | WIN1252  | Portuguese_Brazil.1252 | Portuguese_Brazil.1252 |
```